# Another double fractional part integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, fractional-part

Today I'm trying to defeat another fractional part integral but it seems quite difficult… That is $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left\{\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$ Probably, a way to solve is noticing that for the definition of fractional part function $$\left\{\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right\}=\left\{1+\frac{2y}{x-y}\right\}=\left\{\frac{2y}{x-y}\right\}$$ and it seems somewhat easier. I suppose that the answer is in evaluating the fractional integrand but I have some difficulties with it and the substitutions that I tried weren't very useful. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please note that fractional calculus is not related to the fractional part function (for which we've a separate tag).

Comment: Since there are multiple conventions for fractional parts of negative numbers, and the choice of convention is relevant to the Question, what is the definition of fractional part you are using, or at least, what is $\{-1.3\}$?

Comment: @bianco I feel silly for having started a more complicated answer, have a look at my edit.

Comment: No problem @Ninad Munshi. I only have to thank you for your effort and simply elegant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand has interesting behavior around $y=x$, so let's split the integral there into two pieces. Let's convert the bottom piece into an integral in polar coordinates:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sec \theta} \left\{\frac{\cos\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\cos\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\right\}r\:dr\:d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\{\tan\theta\}\csc^2\theta\:d\theta$$

Now let $u = \cot\theta$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{u}\right\}\:du = \frac{1-\gamma}{2}$$

which is a somewhat fairly known result, depending on who you ask. The top integral should follow similarly, I'll let you try it on your own (aka left to the reader as an exercise!)

---

$\textbf{EDIT}$: Given that the inside of the curly braces is negative on the upper piece as @EricTowers noted, we can use

$$\{-x\} = 1 - \{x\}$$

for noninteger $x$ to get that the integral of the upper piece equals

$$\iint_{\text{upper}} \left\{\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right\}\:dx\:dy = \iint_{\text{lower}}1 - \left\{\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right\}\:dx\:dy$$

which implies the sum of the two pieces is simply

$$\iint_{\text{triangle}} dA = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  Exchanging $x$ and $y$ negates the integrand, $$ \left\{ \frac{x+y}{x-y} \right\} = -\left\{ \frac{y+x}{y-x} \right\} \text{,} $$
so split the region of integration along the line $x = y$.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. $\{1.3\} = 0.3$, but $\{-1.3\} = -0.7$ on the usual convention $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi : "usual convention"?  There are [three usual conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part#For_negative_numbers) for the fractional part of a negative number.  What makes you think any pair of the Question, you, or I agree on that convention?

Comment: I'm basing it off of the definition OP used from [their last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620821/evaluating-int-0n-x2-textdx/3621763#3621763). Also this question would be pretty boring if it used a convention where the integral evaluates to zero via symmetry :)

Comment: @NinadMunshi : Read that Question and its answer twice now.  Neither defines fractional part or uses any negative inputs to the fractional part function.

Comment: In the third line of the post, OP says $\{x^2\} = x^2 - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor$

Comment: @NinadMunshi : Yes.  Everything there is nonnegative.  All three conventions agree for nonnegative inputs.

Comment: I guess that is a good point, then let's use wikipedia's convention where it says the difference convention is denoted by curly braces.

Comment: @NinadMunshi : Even if we decide to pick a convention at random, you have not shown that we agree with OP's convention.

Comment: Wikipedia very clearly says that the difference definition is denoted by curly braces, and that's supported by a lot of literature. Second, what's the big deal? No need to be so uptight, just give an answer for each convention. The odd convention gives $0$. Or we can ask OP for clarification, there's no need to keep dragging it out.

Comment: @Eric Towers : I approve Ninad Munshi

Comment: Sincerely, I think I could not clarify this issue because I also have had this problem and the book isn't very clear about that. But I can say that the answer given by book is exactly $\frac12$... Could you deduce something from this?